# What band/setting is suitable for using SDR in wild area for exchanging beacon messages and alerts?

Tags: software-defined-radio, mesh-network

The problem we try to fix:

We're living in north America. In many wild areas, mostly hilly forest terrain, there's no cellular signal. So far we figured out two solutions: using two-way radio (walkie-talkie) or satellite terminals.
However, we find talking on the radio frequently just to report position is annoying. Also, satellite devices and services are not cheap.

And we found the SDR. So we wonder if we can use it to build a **mesh network** then connect the SDR transceiver to our cellphone, and build an app on our cellphone to share our GPS location every few seconds. Maybe alerts and SOS could be sent and received in the same way.

**Our requirement:**

1. This is to keep us secure when we're hiking by tracking +sharing our positions;
2. Such a solution should not be expensive;
3. It should support text messaging;
4. Not difficult to learn for beginners;
5. As broader range as possible;
6. Should be legal, or it's not hard to get a license;

Our understanding of the actual performance of the SDR transceiver is feeble (range, interference, reliability, etc.). So we're still asking around if SDR is actually not feasible in such a use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think APRS might be what you are looking for:

Automatic Packet Reporting Service.
http://www.aprs.org/

> OVERVIEW: The Automatic Packet Reporting System was designed to support rapid, reliable exchange of information for local, tactical real-time information, events or nets. The concept, which dates back to the mid 1980's, is that all relevant information is transmitted immediately to everyone in the net and every station captures that information for consistent and standard display to all participants.

Can we assume that you are a licensed amateur radio operator?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've checked the APRSdroid as the android app. However, is there any option for a user without license and just want to build an ad-hoc mesh wireless network? Only sharing position in the gruop.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Perhaps someone else will come along with a better answer.

Comment: Having said that, this is now probably [off-topic](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).